# Check for a particular string

Tags: ksh

I may get any or all of the following values from a logfile with this command:

`grep -iw "refresh" ref.log |awk '{print $3}'`

- in_progress
- delayed
- completed
- error

I need to do something if I get anything other than "completed"
and something else if get all "completed"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
bad=$(grep -iw "refresh" ref.log |
      awk '$1!="completed" {bad++} 
      END {print bad}' )

# bad is zero if all is completed

if [ $bad -eq 0 ] ; then  # all good
# do one thing here           
else                      # something went wrong
# do another thing here
fi
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response.  not working ,  if all are not completed or some are not completed , it is fine , going to else part , but if all are completed then also going to else part,  not at all checking  if [ $bad -eq 0 ] . not sure which is missing !  thanks again....